# Sort per same string name and index position

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array where I have a column with equals strings, and a previous column with the information that should be print according to occurrence. I want to print only the alphabetical order of column 9  and do not take in consideration the alphabetical order from column 8.

For example:

```
column 9=[rank 1, rank1, rank 2, rank2, rank 3, rank3, ...]

column 8=[CO,      BR,    IR,     AB,    CB,      CA....]
```

It should give me this  output below, because I want to print by rank 1, rank 2, rank 3, rank 1, rank 2, rank 3:

```
CO IR CB  BR AB CA
```

However, my code take the alphabetic order of column 9 when it find equals strings in column 9. How could I solve. Is there a way to check the index to display the data in that order?

here is my code:

```
function readCsv($fileName){

    $handle = fopen($fileName, "r");


    $data=array();

    while ($col = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) { 

        $data[] = [

            'Section' => $col[0],   
            'Q #' => $col [1],
            'Q Type' => $col[2],
            'Q Title' => $col[3],
            'Q Text' => $col[4],
            'Bonus' => $col [5],
            'Difficulty' => $col[6],
            'Answer' => $col[7],
            'Answer Match' => $col[8],
            'Responses'=> $col[9], 

        ];      

    }

    unset($data[0]); //skip line 1, header
    usort($data, 'cmp');

    fclose($handle);
    return $data;
}
ob_end_flush();



function cmp($a, $b) {

    return $a['Answer Match'] > $b['Answer Match'] (array_search($a['Answer Match'], $a) < array_search($b['Answer Match'], $b)+1);
}
```

Comment: The example does not use valid PHP syntax. Could you actually use data that can be injected directly in the code? The fact that you are reading CSV seems completely irrelevant to the question, as well as the many other values in a row. Please provide an minimal example that focusses on your issue only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/array_multisort) in two passes:

1. First sort by "Answer Match" and "Responses"
2. Add a new column to the data: the sequence number within a group of same "Answer Match" values
3. Sort again, but now by that new column, and then "Answer Match"

Here is the code:

```
// Example data
$data = [
    ["Answer Match" => "rank 3", "Responses" => "CB"],
    ["Answer Match" => "rank 1", "Responses" => "CO"],
    ["Answer Match" => "rank 1", "Responses" => "BR"],
    ["Answer Match" => "rank 2", "Responses" => "IR"],
    ["Answer Match" => "rank 2", "Responses" => "AB"],
    ["Answer Match" => "rank 3", "Responses" => "CA"],
];

// First sort by "Answer Match" and then "Responses":
array_multisort(array_column($data, "Answer Match"), 
                array_column($data, "Responses"), SORT_DESC, $data);

// Then add a new column to the data, which gives the sequence number 
// within the same group of "Answer Match":
foreach($data as $i => $a) {
    $data[$i]["i"] = (!$i or $a["Answer Match"] != $data[$i-1]["Answer Match"]) 
                         ? 1 : $data[$i-1]["i"]+1;
}

// Now sort using that extra column to get the final sort order
array_multisort(array_column($data, "i"), array_column($data, "Answer Match"), $data);

// If it bothers you, the extra column can be removed again.
```

Comment: trincot  why are your first "Answer Match" and then "Responses"? In responses columns has the number 1 for all lines. It get the first 2 correct, and then goes incorrect again.

Comment: Your question states that column 9 has values "rank 1", "rank 2",...etc, and in your code `col[9]` corresponds to "Responses", so I don't understand why you now say that column just has the value 1. Could you update your question to clarify which column contain the values you want to use in your sorting? Also look at the comment I made below your question...